# Install - partitioning problem ('unusable space')

Tags: installation, partitioning, gparted

How can I create another partition (to e.g. parallel install a different ubuntu version) with this current partitioning table? After shrinking `/dev/sda4` there is only this `'unusable'` space?!
My current partitions are as per gparted:

```
/dev/sda
   /dev/sda1 ntfs                (Windows)
   /dev/sda2 ntfs                (Windows)
   /dev/sda5 ext4                (Linux /home)
   /dev/sda7 ntfs                (joint data partition)
   /dev/sda6 swap
   /dev/sda4 ext4   50028 MB     (Oneiric)
   unusable         67000 MB
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have too many partitions created. the count is: sda1 (primary), sda2 (primary), sda5-sda7 (logical partitions inside a extended partition), thats why sda4 comes after all the higher counts. A Master-Boot-Record-formatted disk only allows 4 partitions (primary or logical).
You can use the space by resizing/moving partitions accordingly or eliminate sda4, resize the extended partition (which already contains sda5-sda7 (logical partitions)) to the complete remaining space and create your wanted (logical) partitions inside the extended one.

Comment: Yes, that's right. (I did realise the 4 partitions, and had moved it to superuser, with it not really being just ubuntu related: http://superuser.com/questions/395687/install-how-to-create-additional-partition-currently-unusable-space). Not yet entirely sure yet about where to put the new partition: 'moving' `/dev/sda4` warns me about potential boot corruptions with having the linux OS there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly too sure what you are asking. Are you asking if you can install a different version to /dev/sda4? If so, yes.

But, I'm sure you're asking about the unusable space. Simply, all you have to do is create a partition on that spot. However, it will be located at the end of your partitions.

Now, I'm pretty sure that I answered absolutely nothing. I haven't been asleep in 2 or so days and I'm having comprehension troubles... Ugh. If I didn't answer your question, can you rephrase it for a simpleton such as myself? I really want to be able to help you.

Comment: The essence of the question is: `HOW` can I create another partition there? Gparted doesn't give me that option (unless I just can't find it)?!

Comment: Ah....I see what you mean now. Sorry about that :)

Ok, right click that unusuable space. What all options appear?

Comment: within the ubuntu install, right click doesn't do anything, and the `Add...`, `Change...`, and `Delete` buttons seem inactive when that `unusable` space is selected...

Comment: Ok then, go ahead and boot from Live--either CD or USB. Then give it a try. I'm assuming because you are booted from the ubuntu install and the space is attached...kind of...to that partition, it is preventing editing to it so you don't kill that partition. (I've been through all this before, it can be a drag) Boot from Live and let me know what it says.

Comment: This is all from LIVE CD.

Comment: Misread what you said by "within the ubuntu install"...sorry about that.

Can you regrow that partition again to take up the full space? We can try that and then try to reshrink.