# Install Method "Something Else" unsable device

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, ntfs

So I am trying to install Ubuntu via the "Something Else" method.
I have a 750gb HDD with 286gb used for window 7 the other part of the HDD is broken up into separate drives but is grouped together and is listed as unusable
The 453gb is divided into three drives in windows
20gb ntfs
20gb raw
410gb ntfs with data on it

why does is it not detecting the spare disk space as usable?
will I be able to install Ubuntu along side my windows 7 using this method?
I want to install Ubuntu on one of the 20gb drives I created.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109056/install-partitioning-problem-unusable-space ?

Answer (score 0):

In the short answer yes. You need to make sure the raw free space is not overlapping the other drives. That is why it says up usable. I would go into that pick one of the 20 go sets delete that partition the rest set it in the something else disk menu  just use the plus and minus to do it but be extremely careful only only do it to the free space you intend to install Ubuntu Linux on. Hope this helps.